# Узнать имя домена, на котором запустился iframe с php скриптом

Tags: php, iframe

Есть php скрипт, который выполняется у пользователя в `iframe`, Сприпт находится на одном домене, а `iframe` на другом. Мне нужно сделать проверку по домену пользователя, если такой-то домен существует, то скрипт выполняется.

Проблема в том, что не одним `$_SERVER` элементом нельзя получить удаленный домен клиента. Кроме конечно `HTTP_REFERER`. Все остальные показывают информацию по серверу, на котором запущен сам скрипт (даже `REMOTE_HOST`).

**client.ru**

```
<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="http://server.ru/lib.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

**server.ru**

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
$urlcheck = тут массив с урлами разрешенных клиентов;

if ($url == $urlcheck) {
   echo = 'выполняем скрипт';
}
```

Сам по себе `HTTP_REFERER` мне очень не нравится, потому что его легко можно подменить, но как еще проверить домен клиента?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/175235 и https://toster.ru/q/114617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения любых данных родительского окна в контексте Iframe (если домены не совпадают конечно же), должен быть добавлен код на стороне родительского окна. Саму передачу данных можно организовать через [postMessage](https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage), crossdomain ajax и т.д. В вашем случае для получения домена можно использовать любую html ноду , которая генерирует HTTP запрос:

```html
<!--parent page -->
<script>
   var src='www.yourdomain.com?domain=' + encodeURIComponent(top.document.domain);
   (new Image()).src = src;
</script>
```

Comment: Можете написать пример с нодой на основе моего подключения?

Comment: Получается генерируется get c именем домена, который я уже проверяю. Но ведь человеку ничего не стоит подключить этот же айфрейм на другом неразрешенном домене и указать явно www.yourdomain.com?domain=domain1.ru выпилив из яваскрипта этот обработчик.

Comment: Да, как и любой клиентский код, пользователь имеет доступ к нему и соответственно может отредактировать, переопределять переменные и т.д. Можно обфусцировать, можно даже [шифровать](http://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/128741/) .
Только с серверной стороны у вас не получится это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно увидеть вот такое `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']`, в котором будет как раз то что вам нужно. Но это ключ присутствует только в момент когда iframe открывает страницу.